# Sum of two independent random variables converges in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Show that if $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent random variables for $1 \le n \le \infty$, $X_n \Rightarrow X_{\infty}$, and $Y_n \Rightarrow Y_{\infty}$, then $X_n + Y_n \Rightarrow X_{\infty} + Y_{\infty}$. Where $\Rightarrow$ means converge weakly or converge in distribution.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Wich type of convergence?

Comment: @alexjo converge in distribution, converge weekly

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I got it:

Since $X_n \Rightarrow X_{\infty}$ and $Y_n \Rightarrow Y_{\infty}$, we have $\varphi_{X_n}(t) \to \varphi_{X_\infty}(t)$ for all t, and $\varphi_{Y_n}(t) \to \varphi_{Y_\infty}(t)$ for all $t$ by the continuity theorem. And thus $$ \varphi_{X_n + Y_n} (t) = \varphi_{X_n} (t) \varphi_{Y_n}(t) \to \varphi_{X_\infty}(t)\varphi_{Y_\infty}(t) = \varphi_{X_\infty + Y_\infty}(t)$$ for all $t$. Since both $\varphi_{X_\infty} (t)$ and $\varphi_{Y_\infty}(t)$ are continuous at $0$, $\varphi_{X_\infty + Y_\infty} (t)$ is continuous at $0$. Therefore by continuity theorem we have $X_n + Y_n \Rightarrow X_\infty + Y_\infty$.

Comment: @DevenWare Does that proof work?

Comment: Yes that works. Sorry, it doesn't ping me when you type outside of one of my answers!

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** What happens to the characteristic functions?