# $X_{n} \to X $ in distribution, $Y_{n} \to Y$ in distribution but $X_{n} + Y_{n}$ does not converge to $X + Y$ in distribution?!?

Tags: probability-theory

From my problem set:

Give an example for sequences of random variables $X_{n}$, $X$, $Y_{n}$, $Y$ with $X_{n} \to X$ in distribution, $Y_{n} \to Y$ in distribution but $X_{n} + Y_{n}$ does not converge to $X + Y$ in distribution.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9580/linearity-of-convergence-in-distribution-of-random-variables